# SimpleXML removes tags in node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'd like to parse a XML file which is generated by an application called Folker. It's an application to transcribe spoken text. Sometimes it saves the lines in a good format which can be parsed with SimpleXML but sometimes it doesn't.

This line is good:

```
<contribution speaker-reference="KU" start-reference="TLI_107" end-reference="TLI_109" parse-level="1">
    <unparsed>ich überLEG mir das [nochma:l,]</unparsed>
</contribution>
```

This line is not:

```
<contribution speaker-reference="VK" start-reference="TLI_108" end-reference="TLI_111" parse-level="1">
    <unparsed>[JA:_a; ]<time timepoint-reference="TLI_109"/>ja,<time timepoint-reference="TLI_110"/>also (.) wie [geSAGT;]</unparsed>
</contribution>
```

In the second line SimpleXML removes the tags which are inside the `unparsed` node.

How can I get SimpleXML to not remove these tags but parse it as deeper nodes or outputs as an object for example like this (just in JSON for better understanding):

```
"contribution": {
    "speaker-reference": "VK",
    "start-reference": "TLI_108",
    "end-reference": "TLI_111",
    "parse-level": "1",
    "unparsed": {
        "content": "[JA:_a; ]",
        "time": {
            [
                "timepoint-reference": "TLI_109",
                "content": "ja,"
            ],
            [
                "timepoint-reference": "TLI_110",
                "content": "also (.) wie [geSAGT;]"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not remove them. This works flawlessly (interesting app btw):

```
<?php
$string = '<contribution speaker-reference="VK" start-reference="TLI_108" end-reference="TLI_111" parse-level="1">
    <unparsed>[JA:_a; ]<time timepoint-reference="TLI_109"/>ja,<time timepoint-reference="TLI_110"/>also (.) wie [geSAGT;]</unparsed>
</contribution>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$t = $xml->unparsed->time[0];
print_r($t->attributes());
?>
// output:
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [timepoint-reference] => TLI_109
        )

)
```

You can even iterate over them:

```
$times = $xml->unparsed->children();
foreach ($times as $t) {
    $attributes = $t->attributes());
    // do sth. useful with them afterwards
}
```

**Hint:** Assumingly, you were trying `print_r()` or `var_dump()` on the xml tree. This sometimes gives back opaque results as most of the magic happens behind the scenes. Better use `echo $xml->asXML();` to see the actual XML string.

Comment: You are right. It doesn't remove them but it still doesn't work like I expected or rather want it to work :D
I need the three strings seperated but I think that's a problem with the XML generated by the tool.